# Twitter streaming API - firehose access

Tags: twitter

If We need firehose access for twitter streaming API, which one is best partner Gnit OR datasift ? Also please provide the pricing information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is visit each of their sites and contact them. They all have their own pricing models and you'll have to find out what they're offering. +1 for Gnip, but here's the list of Twitter's Certified Data Providers so you can find the rest:

https://dev.twitter.com/programs/twitter-certified-products/products#Certified-Data-Products

Comment: DISCLAIMER: I work for Gnip :)

The above link is perfect, and you (Raj) should figure out and pick the best provider to meet your needs.

However, if you'd like to explore Gnip, we have a really great sales team who would be happy to walk through your use case and see if and what products of ours would enable those use cases.

You can contact them at info@gnip.com, and you can view a high level overview of our twitter offerings here: http://gnip.com/twitter/